# Identificação de uma solução VSTO

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-studio-2013, deploy, instalador

Implementei um projeto do tipo *Excel* *Workbook* no Visual Studio. O projeto executa direito, meu problema é como instalar isso no computador do cliente.

Não quero um instalador *ClickOnce*, pois o suplemento deve iniciar sempre que o cliente abrir o *Excel*. Por isso, segui o passo-a-passo de [*deploy* usando *installshield*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx).

A instalação ocorre okay, e até vejo o Excel tenta inicializar minha aplicação quando ele é iniciado, entretanto ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Não é possível executar a personalização porque a identificação da
>   solução no documento não corresponde à personalização."

O erro apresentado na janela "Suplementos de COM" quando tento iniciar o suplemento á força é:

> "Não carregado. Erro em tempo de execução durante o carregamento dos
>   suplementos de COM".

Alguém já passou por algo parecido ou o que eu devo fazer para alterar a identificação de modo que funcione? Obrigado.